# Removing Characters and Delete Empty Lines with SED/Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed

I want to remove all 'N's from the data that looks like this:

```
>Seq1
NNNNNNNNA
NNNNNNNNN
ATCGGGGGG
NNNNNNNNN
GTCGGGGGG
>Seq2
GATAAAAAA
NNNNNNNNN
```

So that it returns:

```
>Seq1
AATCGGGGGGGTCGGGGGG
>Seq2
GATAAAAAA
```

But why this doesn't do it:

```
sed -e 's/N//g'
```

What's the correct way to approach this?

Comment: You want to remove the newline also or only the N's ?

Comment: @Raghuram: also newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 'if (!/^>/) { tr/N\n//d } elsif ($. > 1) { $_ = "\n$_" }' input-file
```

Comment: You are missing a newline on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/[N\n]//g'
```

[N\n] matches on either the Ns or the new lines. The rest is taken from [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n).

Comment: ah I'm more familiar with perl and didn't know, sed needs special handling to join the lines +1

Comment: @llion: thanks. But not quite what I want. It puts everything into single line. While what I want is to maintain '>Seq' as its header. See example.

Comment: @neversaint: do you want the first line untouched or do you want special handling for any pattern in the header?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/>Seq/{:a;x;s/N//g;s/\n//2gp;g;x;d};H;$ba;d' file
>Seq1
AATCGGGGGGGTCGGGGGG
>Seq2
GATAAAAAA
```

or this:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/[N\n]//g;s/>Seq[0-9]*/\n&\n/g;s/.//' file
>Seq1
AATCGGGGGGGTCGGGGGG
>Seq2
GATAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `awk` should do the trick -

`awk '!/^N+/' filename`

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat temp
>Seq1
NNNNNNNNA
NNNNNNNNN
ATCGGGGGG
NNNNNNNNN
GTCGGGGGG
>Seq2
GATAAAAAA
NNNNNNNNN

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '!/^N+/' temp
>Seq1
ATCGGGGGG
GTCGGGGGG
>Seq2
GATAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

you need '\n' to match the newline characters:

```
sed -e 's/[N\n]//g'
```

if this doesn't do what you want, please show us, what it does and explain whats different to what you want